# @media (max-width: 640px) not working for mobile

Tags: html, css, ejs

This `codepen` link: https://codepen.io/gianlucaas/pen/bGrmQVO hosts my code for one of my pages for a new website.

the problem is, when I go and test it on mobile (you can try it too, on the codepen link), it looks perfect. you can see the rolex goes to the top right corner (the image) and it looks proper. BUT, when i go to my live link, which is (won't show now for privacy purposes). please see answer that solved issue below...

(ON MY IPHONE), it looks like the desktop application, but it is supposed to look like the phone version! I cannot figure out why for the life of me. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You need `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your head section

Comment: @JHeth thank you! This helped and worked. can't believe i missed that. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need viewport definition in page header, codepen adds that.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
```

Comment: thank you! This helped and worked. can't believe i missed that. appreciate the help.

Comment: Helps if you do the same mistake many times :D

Answer (score 1):

In your codepen you've got the max-width at 640px:

```css
@media (max-width: 640px) {
```

In your live app it's 440px:

```css
@media (max-width: 440px) {
```

Comment: made that mistake for sure. my bad. the issue was though that i was missing the viewport meta tag, as shown above. thanks for your support though!